# Missing run program option in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

I imported a folder of a java solution but when I try to compile and run there is no option to build and run program in IntelliJ. Normally when right clicking on java file there is an option to run. How do I run the program. Please see attached print screen.

[image]

Comment: What if you right click on your src directory and `mark as -> sources root`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because there is no main method inside the class you are highlighting.

Is there a main method?